# Output array after Q queries set some elements to zero

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Q queries are performed on an array A of N elements. In each query, an Index I is chosen and following operation is performed.

```
for j = I + 1 to N:
  if A[j] < A[I]:
    A[j] = 0
```

How does array A looks like after processing the Q queries.

```
1 <= N,Q <= 10^5
1 <= A <= 10^9

Test Case :

5 2 (N Q)  
4 3 4 3 2
3 2 (Q queries) 
solution : 4 3 4 0 0

3 1 (N Q)
3 2 1
2
solution : 3 2 1
```

Hint was to use an **advanced sorting algorithm**.

In the first test case :
Array after 1st query {4, 3, 4, 3, 0}
Array after 2nd query {4, 3, 4, 0, 0}

I tried the brute force approach, traversing every query. Couldn't come up with an efficient approach.

Comment: Seems like the order of the queries doesn't affect the outcome, so the problem becomes finding the most efficient order.

Comment: Can you share a link to the problem?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** findings.

Comment: Hint: prefix array :)

Comment: @MrSmith42 I tried the brute force approach, couldn't come up with an efficient solution.

Comment: @seanzig From where did you get this question?

Comment: @vivek_23 I don't have the link.

Comment: @seanzig Ok, then it's difficult to validate my idea. It was basically to sort the queries(in terms of array values in decreasing order) and set values to 0 accordingly. If some index appeared after the previous max value, we skip it anyway.

Comment: Can elements be negative?

Comment: Why don't second sample has a solution `3 2 0`?

Comment: @גלעדברקן No they have to be greater than 0.

Comment: @vivek_23 Can you explain with an example? Thanks

Comment: @seanzig I could but I am afraid of the time complexity. I would want to first validate the correctness of my approach before putting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first misread the problem and solved the problem for when `A[j] > A[I]` (see below), which seems more interesting :)

To solve the problem for `A[j] < A[I]`, for each element, we'd like to know if there was a greater element to the left that was queried before it may have been set to zero. Surprise! If it was turned to zero before being queried, it means an *even greater* element was queried to the left.

We can solve this in `O(n)` time and `O(|Q|)` space (assuming we use the input space as output). Place the query indexes in a set for `O(1)` lookup. Traverse from left to right and maintain a single variable of the greatest queried element (with starting value 0). If the current element is smaller than `largest_seen_queried_element`, mark it as zero in the output. If the element was queried and is larger than `largest_seen_queried_element`, update `largest_seen_queried_element`.

```
4 3 4 3 2
Queries 3 2

4   largest_queried 0
3   largest_queried 0
4   largest_queried 4
3   < 4 so set to 0 (largest_queried stays the same)
2   < 4 so set to 0
```

#### Solution for `A[j] > A[i]`

We can solve this in `O(n log n)` time and `O(n)` space. Assuming all non-negative elements, for each array element, we'd like to know if there is (1) any lower element to the left that was queried, or (2) given query order as time, any equal or higher element to the left that was queried at time `t`, after being set to zero at some time `t' < t`.

Traverse the array from left to right alongside a list or map of the queries with the additional time flag representing their order (e.g., `[(1, 2), (2, 0)]` would mean index 1 was queried at time 2, and index 2 at time 0).

Maintain a tree of the elements seen so far that were queried, ordered by their value, decorated with the lowest time seen in the left subtree. If the same queried value appears with an earlier time, update the time decoration.

For each element, look in the tree of queried elements for the closest node of lower value. If it exists, mark the element as 0 in the output. If the element was also queried and at a time *later* than the corresponding time decoration we found in the tree, insert the value 0 into the tree of queried elements with the time of the query (or just update the time decoration if 0 is already in the tree with a later time).

Comment: Should we sort the queries?

Comment: @seanzig For your question of A[j] < A[i], you would not need sorting.